# concatenate using Allen Browne's example

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using the 'concatenate related' module created by Allen Browne to concatenate rows into a single field.  At first I had a lookup field at the table level and later realized this is not a good approach.  So I deleted the lookup column and instead made a query for selecting values from the lookup table on my form and then store that value as a number in the table.

The module works when I concatenate the values but it is listing the number (id) whereas I would like the actual description (i.e. 1 = Red, 2 = Blue, etc.)

My SQL query code is as follows:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    tblCompany.JobID,
    concatrelated("type","tblMonitor","JobID = " & [jobID]) AS Expr1
FROM tblCompany;
```

I would like "type" to display the description instead of the number.  I know if I store my lookup value as text instead of number it will work.  But for efficiency it seems the number should be stored in the table and then query for the description when you need it....or maybe text is fine???  I'm guessing I would need to add the lookup table to this query.  I have tried but with no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query which joins `tblMonitor` with the table which holds the type description field.  Then use that query with `ConcatRelated`.

```sql
ConcatRelated("type_descriptn","YourQuery","JobID = " & [jobID])
```

Comment: Nice work!  I keep forgetting/not realizing how useful queries are.  I still have much to learn obviously so this will come in handy.  Thanks for your time.